# I want to print hello before CoreFoundation.dylib loads in ios

Tags: dynamic-linking, dylib, core-foundation

I want to print hello before CoreFoundation.dylib loads in ios build process. For instance if you create a new ios application and remove all the files and add main.c inside which you print helloworld it gets print after the CoreFoundation.dylib is loaded. I do not want that I want to print "Hello World" just before CoreFoundation.dylib loads
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

(Note: you must edit scheme -> Run -> arguments -> Environment Variable -> add name "DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES" and value 0 in order to see the .dylib loads in the console logs)

Comment: Are you still linking against CoreFoundation?